# Loading profile only with parameter without the need to key in Kohana 3.x

Tags: kohana-3, routes

I'm new to Kohana 3.x. Would you like a website with Kohana with User profile style twitter. Example: https://twitter.com/maronems to load the profile is passed only paramentro maronems without the need to pass the key = parameter. Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "key = parameter" I assume you mean something like `http://twitter.com?user=maronems` right? This is **ugly**, we can do better.

Let's look at making your URLs look like `http://twitter.com/maronems` instead.

You'll want to look at [Kohana's routing system](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing).

Take a look at this route:

```php
Route::set('username route', '<username>')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'Profile',
    'action'     => 'index', 
));
```

- Firstly, it's called `username route`, this is an aribitrary name,
  but a good one because it's intent is clear.
- Next look at the regex pattern `<username>`. This route is going to capture the username and store it in a variable called `username`.
- Now notice that the route doesn't have to specify the controller and action. The routing system will get those from the default values. In this example you'll need a controller called `Controller_Profile` with an action called `action_index`.

So let's look at the controller now:

```php
<?php 

class Controller_Profile extends Controller {

    function action_index()
    {
        echo 'Hello ' . $this->request->param('username');
    }

}
```

Of course you shouldn't user echo like this in classes, but to illustrate the point, if you visit `example.com/maronems` you should see `Hello maronems` echoed out.